# How can I reuse MyBatis mappers?

Tags: mybatis

Let's say there are two tables. One is parent and the other is child.

I have sql mappers for each table.

How can I use child's sql mapper in parent's mapper?

I mean I want to implement `ON DELETE CASCADE`. My database, unfortunately, doesn't support that feature.

In my child mapper, I have...

```xml
<delete id="deleteChildren" ...>
    DELETE FROM CHILD WHERE PARENT_ID = #{parentId}
</delete>
```

In my parent mapper I just want to

```xml
<delete id="deleteParent" ...>
    <!-- call `deleteChildren` here -->
    <!-- ant then delete the parent -->
    DELETE FROM PARENT WHERE ID = #{id}
</delete>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run two queries in just one fragment and reuse the other fragment using `include`. But the SQL syntax depends of your database.

In MySQL:

```
<delete id="deleteParent" ...>
    <include refid="Child.deleteChildren" />;
    DELETE FROM PARENT WHERE ID = #{id};
</delete>
```

In MS-SQL:

```
<delete id="deleteParent" ...>
    <include refid="Child.deleteChildren" />
    GO
    DELETE FROM PARENT WHERE ID = #{id}
</delete>
```

Comment: What does `GO` do anyway?

Comment: It allows you to run two (or more) queries at the same time.